# StorageFolder find hidden files

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, file-storage

I have some hidden files in my storage but I cannot find a way how to get these files.

```
var rootFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
var logFolder= await rootFolder.GetFolderAsync("Logging");
var logFiles = await logFolder.GetFilesAsync(CommonFileQuery.DefaultQuery);
```

logFiles is always zero.

Is there a way to retrieve hidden files?

Comment: Could you please update what if you found a solution or as I told you, you can't ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, the StorageFile cannot get the hidden files, here's a confirmation:
https://mtaulty.com/2013/02/22/m_14585/

Comment: hmm then the big question is how it is possible that some files are marked as hidden. Thanks